# in shell script,how to get file name after untar the file

Tags: shell

i am having tar file "test.tar.gz'.now i want to get the name "test' after untar the "test.tar.gz'. In shell script ,how to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

```
file="test.tar.gz"
tarfilename=${file%.tar.gz}
```

read up about it `man bash` search for variable expansion.

Comment: should be `${file%.tar.gz}` with a dot before the "tar"

Answer (score 3):

To strip an extension from a file name, use `basename`:

```
basename test.tar.gz .tar.gz
```

prints `test`

But that is just the base name of the archive. It's *not always* the name of any file or directory which the `tar` creates. The tar archive can contain any file names. If you need those, use `tar tf` to list the content of the archive.